# What's wrong with a new playground file?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8, swift-playground

Just create a new playground file, got this without doing anything

> failed to launch process. The folder "disabled.plist" doesn't exist.

Quit Xcode and restart, even remove 'Xcode/DerivedData', doesn't have any help.

How could fix it?

[image]

Comment: Nothing. Playground is [buggy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46531754/compiler-segmentation-fault-while-using-set-in-swift/46534410#46534410) like hell. Many times the solution I have is to do a restart

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I just fixed it.

Turns out somehow I was removed from having permission to write to `/private/temp` directory.

To solve it:

**Using CMD**

Update the permission of your temp folder using:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /private/temp`

**Repairing with Disk Utility**

If you are using OS X 10.10 ("Yosemite") or earlier, 
Try to fix the problem by using the OS X Disk Utility program:

1. Launch Disk Utility. It is located in `/Applications/Utilities`.
2. Select the computer's boot volume (usually "Macintosh HD") in the left column.
3. Click on the "Repair Disk Permissions" button".
4. Wait until the permissions repair is complete (it usually takes several minutes).
5. Quit Disk Utility.
6. Launch Xcode and to see if the problem has been fixed.

Hope it helps someone

Comment: What is /temp/, did you mean /tmp?

Comment: Yes, it's `/temp`. Updated my answer.

Comment: That's strange, there is no /temp directory on OS X. Something you created yourself or are you not running OS X?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Fixed and updated answer with other methods. Thanks